# jQuery file tree: file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm using  the jquery file tree (http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) and the jsp connector version.

So, the javascript code is:

```
    $(function() {
     $("#container_id").fileTree({ 
       root: '/home/mio' ,
       script: '/Grafo_Filesystem-portlet/jqueryFileTree.jsp',
     }, function(file) {
       alert(file);
     });
    });
```

When I click on the file name, an alert with the file path is returned.

Instead, I'd like downloading the file. How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a cross-browser solution: when a file is selected, an hidden GET form is submitted in another page ( so you don't lose the actual page with the file tree opened ) and the browser will take care of downloading the content of the file.

```
$(function() {
    $("#container_id").fileTree({ 
            root: '/home/mio' ,
            script: '/Grafo_Filesystem-portlet/jqueryFileTree.jsp',
        },
        function(file) {
            $('#hiddenForm').attr('action', file);
            $('#hiddenForm input[name="rand"]').val(Math.floor(Math.random()*1001));
            $('#hiddenForm').submit();
        }
    );
});

## HTML PART ( PUT AT THE END OF THE PAGE ) ##
<form id="hiddenForm" action="#" target="_blank" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="rand" value="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the solution you proposed but nothing happens. I put the html at the end of the jsp file, is it correct?

Comment: 1) The other solutions posted here are cross-browser as well. 2) A form isn't supposed to have a `src` attribute

Comment: Asad, none of the proposed solutions triggers a result. No error on the console, no result.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it's ACTION for the form, not SRC: this happened because I wanted to go with the iframe solution, but then noticed that the form method was the best. Replace $('#hiddenForm').attr('src', file); with $('#hiddenForm').attr('action', file); and <form id="hiddenForm" src="#" with <form id="hiddenForm" action="#"

Comment: @Maurizio, which could be the reason why your solution does not trigger any effect? I didn't see error on Firebug console, but no download is performed. Thanks.

Comment: @user1052004 try this fiddle in the browser you're using for the development of your page and tell us if it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/xa5Xb/2/

Comment: In your function, if you do an alert(file); can you tell us if the string is a complete url or only a url path of linux/windows?

Comment: It is just an url path of windows. In particular, the path specified as 'root' in fileTree function plus the file name (that is: /home/mio/log.txt).

Comment: have you tried appending a "file://" before the file path? Try to type in your nevigation bar the file://test_a_file_path and see what happens. If the file is downloaded, modify my script so that the file:// is appended before the file path

Comment: If I write "file:///C:/home/mio/log.txt" in the navigation bar I can see the file. But, if I append "file:///C:" before file path in your script nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 $("#container_id").fileTree({ 
   root: '/home/mio' ,
   script: '/Grafo_Filesystem-portlet/jqueryFileTree.jsp',
 }, function(file) {
   window.location.replace(file);
 });
});
```